# Can't get the whole souce of a page in android

Tags: android, html, androidhttpclient

i'd just wanted to get the source of the page for parsing data.
I used the following code

```
public static String getPageSourceFromUrl(String Url) {
        String text = "";
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        text = str.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return text;
}
```

and the page is : " http://vn.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111022210730AAWvfKI "

Unfortunately,in some pages (like the one above) , the text return is just a part of the whole source. maybe the string is exceed the limit, so anyone has any solution ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sorry,it was very long time ago, so i can't remember what i going to ask here :(

Comment: Then please accept my solution I was able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve (our) problem. The elegant way is to create a class:

```
public class GetRating {

    public GetRating(){

    }

    public String GetRatingFromURL(String url){

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); // Set the action you want to do
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } // Executeit


        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = null;


        try {
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } // Create an InputStream with the response


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;


        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here


        return resString;


    }


}
```

Then call it from another class:

```
GetRating GN = new GetRating();
String pagesource = GN.GetRatingFromURL(url)("http://somewebpage.com");
```